# Why is property injection needed in Blazor components

Tags: dependency-injection, blazor-webassembly

Making my hands dirty with Blazor, I observed regular Ctor injection is not working, found that we need to use property injection with Inject attribute. Can someone enlighten me why?

I have an employee overview class. If I enable Ctor injection(uncomment parameter and assignment as shown below) and comment out Inject attribute, it does not work. Why? Or am I missing something here.

```
public partial class EmployeeOverview //: PageModel
{
    public EmployeeOverview(
        //IEmployeeDataService employeeDataService
        )
    {
        //_EmployeeDataService = employeeDataService;
    }

    [Inject]
    private IEmployeeDataService _EmployeeDataService { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to check out the docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server

Comment: This question can probably only be answered by people from the Blazor team at Microsoft.

Comment: That said, due to the negative consequences the choice for property injection has on parties trying to integrate with Razor (such as myself, as I try to let my Simple Injector users [integrate](https://docs.simpleinjector.org/en/latest/blazorintegration.html) with Blazor), I would like to see an answer on this question from MS.